# Probability Argument

Tags: probability

A student observes that out of all students achieving A* in Science,95% of them have passed their Biology mid term. As the student has just passed the test they claim that they have a good chance of getting an A*. Explain if their argument has any basis from a probabilistic point of view .

My Solution:
No, from a probabilistic point of view this argument does not stand as we do not know the probability of students achieving an A* AND passing the mid term

How can I word it better if that's the correct solution? if not, please let me know

Comment: What if 95% of all students passed their January Mocks?

Comment: Suppose that the january mock had one question which was "calculate  the result of 1 + 1.".

Comment: @EthanBolker are you saying it stands from a probabilistic point of view? if so how?

Comment: My comment shows that the data you have predict nothing about that student.

Comment: @markleeds Would that question have led to a mere 95% pass rate?

Comment: @EthanBolker What do you mean? The data I have about the student is that she has passed the mid term

Comment: I'll help you word it better, because I feel like this is just "affirming the consequent", a probabilistic version of it. So let $E_1,E_2$ be respectively the event that a student obtains A* in Science, and the event that they pass the Biology midterm. What you do know, is that $P(E_2|E_1) = 0.95$. However, for the student in question, $E_2$ has occurred and they expect that $E_1$ will occur as well. That means the student is then assuming that $P(E_1|E_2)$ is large : which need not be true, and follows from what you wrote clearly : $E_1 \cap E_2$'s probability is NOT given.

Comment: Suppose there were an elite private school that gets 5,000 entries a year but only selects 20 students a year, 19 from California and 1 from somewhere else.  Suppose a person from California said "95% of the accepted applicants are from California like me.  My chances are good".  Are they?

Comment: @fleablood no but why ?

Comment: I believe @SarveshRavichandranIyer comment probably covers it.

Comment: And it does : because in the example stated above, one sees that if $E_1$ is the event that the person is from California, and $E_2$ is the event that the person is selected, then $P(E_1|E_2) = 0.95$ because that's $19$ out of $20$ people. However, $P(E_2 | E_1)$ is : well, we don't know what $P(E_1)$ is , but say $90$ percent of those applications came from California. Then $P(E_2|E_1)$ is $19/4500$, which is terribly small to say the least. Time for you to deflate that student. @fleablood Thank you for the example.

Comment: Ahh I see it makes sense when you put it into probability formulas thanks !

Comment: @Ethan Bolker: By using an extreme example, I was attempting to explain that the difficulty of the mock exam matters and leads  to one not being able to  infer anything from the statement. I guess that my attempt was unsuccessful !!!!!!

Comment: Well, I was assuming everybody from everywhere applies regularly but the selectors had a california bias and that there'd be as many applicants from california as anywhere else.  So there'd be 100 californians vying for 19 spots.  Not good (although better than any one else which is 4900 vying for 1 spot).  But I guess if I assume that california is the most populous state (not my intent) it's actually more like 500 californians vying for 19 spots and 4000 non-californians vying for 1 spot).  Thing is *everyone's* chances are bad.

Comment: Actually it makes sense that this school would have a reputation and most non-californians would be too discouraged to apply so 90% california rate is reasonable.  It seems the more californians apply the worst the chances are.  But to have even a 50% chance the student must count on only 38 californian applicants but as there are 5000 applicants we can assume that aint gonna happen.